# issue with writing image files from an array to disc: No such file or directory - when using 'w'

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping, capybara-webkit, open-uri

The following program does almost everything I want it to but it won't write the image files to disc that are scraped. The latest error has no such file or directory for the basename of one of the image files that I would like to obtain. It should be writing the new file but I guess I'm doing something wrong. Error: No such file or directory - h3130gy1-3-7ec5.jpg . Ideally this program would write each image to disc with the name of each image being the basename of the absolute url that was used to obtain it. I would also like the spreadsheet element to write the basename of each scraped image to the output file that is being compiled.

```
require "capybara/dsl"
require "spreadsheet"
require "fileutils"
require "open-uri"

 LOCAL_DIR = 'data-hold/images'

 FileUtils.makedirs(LOCAL_DIR) unless File.exists?LOCAL_DIR
 Capybara.run_server = false
 Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
 Capybara.default_selector = :xpath
 Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'

 class Tomtop
   include Capybara::DSL

   def initialize
     @excel = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
     @work_list = @excel.create_worksheet
     @row = 0
   end

   def go
     visit_main_link
   end

   def visit_main_link
     visit "http://www.example.com/clothing-accessories?dir=asc&limit=72&order=position"
     results = all("//h5/a[contains(@onclick, 'analyticsLog')]")
     item = []

     results.each do |a|
       item << a[:href]
     end
     item.each do |link|
          visit link
          save_item
      end
     @excel.write "inventory.csv"

   end

   def save_item

     data = all("//*[@id='content-wrapper']/div[2]/div/div")
     data.each do |info|
       @work_list[@row, 0] = info.find("//*[@id='productright']/div/div[1]/h1").text
       price = info.first("//div[contains(@class, 'price font left')]")
       @work_list[@row, 1] = (price.text.to_f * 1.33).round(2) if price
       @work_list[@row, 2] = info.find("//*[@id='productright']/div/div[11]").text
       @work_list[@row, 3] = info.find("//*[@id='tabcontent1']/div/div").text.strip
       color = info.all("//dd[1]//select[contains(@name, 'options')]//*[@price='0']")
       @work_list[@row, 4] = color.collect(&:text).join(', ')
       size = info.all("//dd[2]//select[contains(@name, 'options')]//*[@price='0']")
       @work_list[@row, 5] = size.collect(&:text).join(', ')
       imagelink = info.all("//*[@rel='lightbox[rotation]']")
       @work_list[@row, 6] = imagelink.map { |link| link['href'] }.join(', ')  
       image = imagelink.map { |link| link['href'] }
       File.open (File.basename("#{LOCAL_DIR}/#{image}", 'w')) do |f|
         f.write(open(image).read)
       end
       @row = @row + 1
     end

   end

 end


 tomtop = Tomtop.new
 tomtop.go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if you have a parenthesis misplaced, this line:

```
File.open (File.basename("#{LOCAL_DIR}/#{image}", 'w')) do |f|
```

Should be this:

```
File.open(File.basename("#{LOCAL_DIR}/#{image}"), 'w') do |f|
```

But actually, on further investigation of your code, it appears that File.basename is acting on the incorrect string in this situation. After getting your code to run, it filled the root folder of scraper.rb with images. So, what I think you really want for that line is this:

```
#only grab the basename of the image, then concatenate that to the end of the local_dir:
filename = "#{LOCAL_DIR}/#{File.basename(image)}"
File.open(filename, 'w') do |f|
```

After running this, I got to the next problem. It appears as though 'image' is an array which contains many urls.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may need to do some additional filtering to get the image down to a single image, or change it to 'images' and have the following code:

```
images = imagelink.map { |link| link['href'] }
images.each do |image|
  File.open(File.basename("#{LOCAL_DIR}/#{image}"), 'w') do |f|
    f.write(open(image).read)
  end
end
@row = @row + 1
```

Comment: This works well I just have to fix a problem with handling 503 exceptions during the download. What about the question of the spreadsheet file that is compiled; I would like that to reference the basename as well when writing but currently it uses the entire url, any thoughts?

Comment: For that, you could do something like this: 
`@work_list[@row, 6] = imagelink.map { |link| File.basename(link['href']) }.join(', ')`

Comment: It works and you've been a great resource Joe; Here is the current code: https://github.com/oldsouless/morbidqueso/blob/master/tomtest.rb ; Can you help me check if my try_repeatedly method is invoked properly. Also I would like to implement a find next link method to get the url for the next page of results something like this: next_results_link = page.at("//td[contains(@class, 'pages')]//a[img/@alt='Next Page']")
  
    if next_results_link
      list_url = next_results_link['href']
      puts "\t...Getting next page of results: #{list_url}"
    else
      break
    end

Comment: What would be the best way to set that up using capybara.